# Send App Center telemetry events from UWP Background Task

Tags: uwp, background-task, visual-studio-app-center, telemetry

I implemented an UWP app with an out-of-process Background Task and configured the app to send telemetry to [App Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/).
The problem is that all the events generated by the app are correctly collected on App Center, instead I cannot see any event sent by the Background Task.
This is my Background Task code.

```
public sealed class MyBackgroundTask : IBackgroundTask
{
    BackgroundTaskDeferral _deferral; 

    public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        AppCenter.Start(id, typeof(Analytics));
        Analytics.TrackEvent("Started");

        _deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();           
        // Some async work
        _deferral.Complete();

        Analytics.TrackEvent("Completed");
    }
}
```

I thought it should be correct call the `AppCenter.Start` method, since it is a new process, but I am not sure about it. Anyway, I tried to omit that instruction, but it didn't work.

Comment: You could [enable verbose log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/other-apis/uwp#adjust-the-log-level) to check if it actually send data. You could also check the Log Flow to see if there're real-time data sent to the app center portal.

Comment: More information, please click the blue chatbox in the bottom right corner of the app center protal to open a new case.

Comment: Hi Xavier, thanks for your reply, but no data are showing up in the Log Flow screen. I think to open a new case as you suggested. I'll share some update if something new comes up.